# Problem when reading html from database

Tags: php, html

I have the following stored in the database.

```
To view your new profile comment, go to your <a href='profile.php?id=1#comments'>profile</a>.
```

When selecting this in the message viewer,

```
profile.' />

To view your new profile comment, go to your profile.
```

The `profile.' />` actually breaks the script and ruins the design.

Is there any reason why this is happening that anyone is aware of?

Thanks

Comment: What does this look like in the HTML source code?

Comment: Could you elaborate more please? Are you using a framework, which one? Which database? Are you using any kind of template system?

Comment: You are providing very little info. Would be hard to assist you this way my friend.

Comment: Fixed this, used double quotes instead of singles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using PHP, you can use htmlentities to convert the characters into HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

It's hardly recommended not to store any html in the database.
Regarding of that, it must be a quotation issue, you should check that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the html to achieve something like escaping the `'` as `\'`. If you're using php you could use something like htmlspecialchars for example. http://uk.php.net/htmlspecialchars.

Or even better http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php.